# Hugo change landingPageURL so that links point to path not URL root

Tags: url, hugo

hey i am struggling with a hugo issue
my blog is hosted at xyz.com/blog so to get my URLs to pages working I have added `baseURL = 'xyz.com/blog/'` to my config.toml file

This works for all page (markdown page) links, however the issue I am having is that the logo/Home link in the menu (theme is [hugo-theme-learn](https://learn.netlify.app/en/)) don't update and always end up linking to the root domain /
I can see from the template that the logo is linked from

```
<a id="logo" href='{{ (cond (and (ne .Site.Params.landingPageURL nil) (.Site.IsMultiLingual)) .Site.Params.landingPageURL "/") }}'>
```

and the home menu button is linked from

```
<a class="padding" href='{{ (cond (and (ne .Site.Params.landingPageURL nil) (.Site.IsMultiLingual)) .Site.Params.landingPageURL "/") }}'>
```

what I can't seem to get working is setting .Site.Params.landingPageURL in the config? I have tried setting

```
[params]
landingPageURL='https://xyz.como/blog'
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever on these two links and they still end up pointing to `/`

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That conditional requires `IsMultiLingual` to be set, otherwise the link defaults to `/`.

Comment: thanks - thats a bit annoying that to get a path i have to enable a second language, but thank you anyway!

Comment: It might just be a bug with that theme.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is a theme specific question - this question or any code updates you propose should go to the maker of the theme, editing the theme yourself, defeats in a small part, the purpose of using a theme.

So, pardon, I'm having difficutly tracking totally and the quoted code is overly complicated (I assume it's from the theme) and maybe has a greater purpose, but if you are in fact trying to link to the baseURL, then just do so:

```
.Site.BaseURL
```

Or

```
site.BaseURL
```

That will return your baseURL... which from your explanation I believe is what you are trying to connect to.

So:

```
<a href=".Site.BaseURL">Home</a>
```

But, even more so:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

If Multilanguage is set-up correctly - does work (at least on the multiple multi-language sites I administer in hugo).

But, again you are then breaking the theme.